# How to group and name series chart in visual studio c#

Tags: c#

I have DataGridView which consist of these data [image: sample DGV data]

From these data i would like to make the first column, airport name to group the third column and sum to their corresponding ActLoadQuantityTo which is in the fifth column, the cargo type which landed on the airport. right now my chart is messed up as it look like this

```
for (int j = 0; j < dgv_3.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            double Load_qty = 0;
            double new_load_qty = 0;
            DiscPort = dgv_3.Rows[j].Cells["ActDiscDischargingPort"].Value.ToString();
            DestType = dgv_3.Rows[j].Cells["SchLoadDestination"].Value.ToString();
            CargoType = dgv_3.Rows[j].Cells["SchLoadCargoType"].Value.ToString();
            string CargoType2 = "Series-" + CargoType;
            Load_qty = Convert.ToDouble(dgv_3.Rows[j].Cells["ActLoadQuantityTon"].Value);
            if (chart3.Series.IndexOf(DiscPort) != -1)
            {
                chart3.Series["000 - Port"].Points.AddY(Load_qty);
            }
            else
            {
                chart3.Series["000 - Port"].Points.AddXY(DiscPort, Load_qty);
            }
        }
```

[image]

no grouping of series,etc. i've tried adding more series but it just doesn't make sense toward the DataGridView. and my expectation is that i would like the chart to look like this as I've described before

[image]

Any idea what set of code should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my desired result by using this code

```
public void isichartdomestic(System.Data.DataTable initialDataSource)
        {
            chart3.Titles.Add("Your title");
            chart3.Legends.Add("Your Legend");
             for (int i = 1; i < initialDataSource.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
                foreach (DataRow dr in initialDataSource.Rows)
                {
                    double y = (double)dr[i];
                    series.Points.AddXY(dr["DiscPort"].ToString(), y);
                    TotalDomestic += y;
                }
                chart3.Series.Add(series);
                string NamaSeries = series.ToString();
                NamaSeries = NamaSeries.Replace("Series-","");
                chart3.Series[NamaSeries].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                chart3.Series[NamaSeries].IsVisibleInLegend = true;
                if (NamaSeries == "Series1")
                {
                    chart3.Series[NamaSeries].LegendText = "Bag";
                }
                else if (NamaSeries == "Series2")
                {
                    chart3.Series[NamaSeries].LegendText = "Bulk";
                }
                else if (NamaSeries == "Series3")
                {
                    chart3.Series[NamaSeries].LegendText = "Clinker";
                }
                else if (NamaSeries == "Series4")
                {
                    chart3.Series[NamaSeries].LegendText = "Container";
                }
            }
            lb_TotalDomestic.Text = Convert.ToString("Total Domestic: " + TotalDomestic);
            TotalDomesticExport += TotalDomestic;

        }
```

[image]